# Running PHP script via Cron

Tags: php, api, cron, instagram

I'm codding a php script, using Instagram Private PHP Api.

It's work fine via SSH under "root" user, but when I try to run it via browser or cron, I getting error: **Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in .....**

I guess that something wrong with permissions, but I am not really good in server administration and can't understand what I can do =(

Please help, how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mcve] and [ask]. Use the edit link below your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Apache (or the web server you're using) executes PHP using different Linux user (usually `www-data`), which obviously have different permission than the user account you used in access via SSH.

To tackle the problem, you first have to know the folder / file you're going to `chmod()` belongs to who. If it belongs to `root`, then it's not suggested to `chmod` via any scripts that is accessible by public due to security concerns.

If it belongs to your user name, say `foo`, you can change the ownership of the folder / file you're going to `chmod()` to be accessible by `www-data` group using `chown()` in SSH console, then you `chmod()` command can be executed without problem.

Comment: I checked. It belongs to root

Answer (score 0):

The user that PHP runs as must have permissions to chmod the given file or directory. If you're running this script via CRON, you get to set the user that PHP runs as right in the CRON job. If you're visiting the script in a browser, PHP is likely running as php or php-fpm or the web server user.

Simply ensure that the given file or folder is owned by the user that PHP runs as.

**Note:** It is *not* recommended that you run this script as root in CRON.

Comment: I'm afraid you do not tell the OP something new. You should explain **how** he ensures that the user has permissions... *'Simply ensure that the user has permissions to chmod the given file or directory.'*

Comment: When I am running it from SSH, I am loggin in as root, so when I write in console **php test.php** it works, everithing is fine, but when I try to run it from my browser http://mywebsite.com/test.php, I am getting error Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in .....

Answer (score -1):

If you are editing `/etc/crontab`, make sure the user parameter (the one after week) is **root**.

If you are editing crontab via `crontab -e`, add user parameter `crontab -eu root`.

Comment: This is a dangerous suggestion.

Comment: If the target is owned by the root user, do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: Change the target's ownership. While it's *possible* to run the cron as root, it gives that script far too much power. We can't verify that this script isn't susceptible to code execution attacks. If it isn't, a future change might make it susceptible. If a bad actor uses this script to execute their own code, that code will be running with root privileges.

Comment: Since you can't verify the script, how could you say this is dangerous? Please refer to the post, OP says he has already run the script via root user and succeeded, then he want to run it via cron, these 2 actions have causal correlation, but you suggest him to change the target's ownership, the previous test is invalid and need login as another user then run the script again. the condition of this question now is entirely broken.

Comment: The OP has expressed inexperience with Linux. Since there's no mention of PHP experience, I prefer to not to assume that the OP is experienced in PHP and security. Suggesting to run the chron as root without expressing the danger of it is..... dangerous.